# Oracle CASE expression documentation issue

Tags: sql, oracle

In the SQL Language Reference for Oracle 11g R2, the documentation for the [simple CASE expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF52074) says that:

> You cannot specify the literal NULL for every return_expr and the else_expr.

However the following SQL executes without problem and returns null:

```
select case 'test' 
        when 'test' then null 
        else null 
        end "Null Test" 
from dual;
```

Is this a problem with the documentation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have at least one not null return expression when your case expression(whether it's simple or search case expression) is used inside a PL/SQL block. In SQL this restriction is relaxed:

> Is this a problem with the documentation or am I missing something

It seems like a minor documentation bug.

SQL:

```
SQL> select case 1
  2           when 1 then null
  3           else null
  4         end as res
  5    from dual
  6  ;
```

Result:

```
RES
---
null
```

PL/SQL:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_res number;
  3  begin
  4   l_res := case 1
  5              when 1 then null
  6              else null
  7            end;
  8  end;
  9  /

ORA-06550: line 4, column 11:
PLS-00617: at least one result in the CASE expression must not be NULL
ORA-06550: line 4, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Respect! I forgot about the difference!

Comment: I found that comment in the 10.2 manual but not the 11.2 manual that you linked to. Maybe they fixed the documentation bug between 10.2 and 11.2.